# What are the tracking resolutions of the various iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm interested in the tracking (read: touch) resolution of the various iOS devices. Specifically, I'm wondering how the iPad compares to the iPhone. Is there official (or any) documentation on this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All iOS devices provide point-level tracking of touch events. Retina displays have grids of 4 pixels per point, but no added tracking resolution.

- iPhones/iPods: 480x320
- iPad 1024x768

Comment: The iPad has a slightly lower DPI, so it'll be slightly lower (approx. 130 vs 160, I think)

Comment: Its DPI is lower, but the OP was regarding resolution, not density.

Comment: Both answer and comment were extremely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Translating that to real-world touches, the DPI could make a difference depending on the application of this info. Draw a line one inch long on the screen or something like that maybe… (sorry, bad example)